# Get files from a google cloud virtual machine to a google collaboratory notebook

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I have files in a virtual machine hosted and created in Google Cloud and I want to be able to access them in google colab to run selenium.

Should I send the files to Google storage? It seems that I would then be able to ve found a tutorial [there](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-access-files-from-google-cloud-storage-in-colab-notebooks-8edaf9e6c020), it shows me how to access Google Cloud Storage files in Colab Notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many methods to upload the files from your Compute Engine machine, for example uploading the files to Google Drive, or Google Cloud Storage. [This document](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) explains it well. Note that your CE machine wouldn't be stricty "local" to you but it would act the same way in that context.

With Cloud Storage, you can use `gsutil` to upload the files, with this command:

```
gsutil cp $file_to_upload gs://$bucket_name
```